# @patch.multiple for inner class in mock python

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, mocking, python-mock

I'm trying to patch an inner class in a more permanent fashion.

I have a class as

```
class OuterClass:
   def _init__(self, s, b):
      self._b = b
      self._inner = InnerClass(s)
```

I have to create a mock instance of the OuterClass and add it to a collection so I tried

```
class MockOuter(OuterClass):

   @patch.multiple(
       InnerClass,
       __init__=MagicMock(side_effect=mock_init),


   )
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super().__init__(s='MockS', b='MockB')
```

so ideally to do

```
   a = MockOuter()
   col.append(a)
```

But once you are out of the init, you lose the patch. Clearly this isn't the right approach, what's the best approach here?

Comment: Why would you need the patch to still be applied (on the `__init__` function) after you exited it ?

Comment: I need to use MockOuter instance later. At that time, the inner mock is lost.

Comment: But the instance has already been `__init__`'d, why do you still need a patch on this specific method ? Look at which fields you instance has after : those that you set in your side effect.